# Snake loader css animation keyframes doesn't work

Tags: css, animation, spinner, keyframe

Im trying to make a snake loader spinner with css using keyframes animation but i don't know it doesn't work
someone can help?
here the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fs6kafsn/

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spinner {
     display: block;
     margin: 50px;
     height: 28px;
     width: 28px;
     animation: rotate 0.8s infinitelinear!important;
     -webkit-animation: rotate 0.8s infinitelinear!important;
     border: 8px solid red;
     border-right-color: transparent;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position:relative;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to save the fiddle :) and its blank.

Comment: you are so fast im just editing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add prefixing to your keyframes as well.

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fs6kafsn/5/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

This would need to be prefixed with -moz- as well for firefox compatibility.

**Note**

the unprefixed version should always be placed after the prefixed versions.

**Full Demo**

```css
.spinner {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;    
    -webkit-animation: rotate 0.8s infinite linear !important;
    -moz-animation: rotate 0.8s infinite linear !important;
    animation: rotate 0.8s infinite linear !important;
    border: 8px solid red;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
   <div class="spinner">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For webkit based browser like chrome you need `@-webkit-keyframes` and for Mozilla firefox you need `@-moz-keyframes`

```css
@keyframes spin {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0%    { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%  { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spinner {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    animation: spin 0.8s infinite linear!important;
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s infinite linear!important;
    border: 8px solid red;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
   <div class="spinner">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your fiddle. Here is the working animation: [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/fs6kafsn/3/):

---

Code:

```
@-moz-keyframes myanimation /* Firefox */
{
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanimation /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.spinner {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    -moz-animation:myanimation 0.8s infinite linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:myanimation 0.8s infinite linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    border: 8px solid red;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JanSpurny this pretty much answers the question. Petroff should have added some key part of the code, but otherwise this is very valid.

Comment: @JanSpurny The fiddle do the exact what he wanted. Why you thing it's not a answer?

Comment: I believe the answer should be *in the answer itself* on stackoverflow. And I also believe in providing helpful explanations in an answer, not just a link, even if the link is helpful. Your answer is just at reference to edit you made. That's probably why jbutler483's answer was accepted and yours was not. However I think you're partially right in that I've probably selected wrong comment.

Comment: Answers should be more than just links, as link-only answers are subject to removal. See this question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Barranka thanks to add the code snippet.
@Qantas94Heavy Thanks for link and feedback, but i still thing if the link answer the question, its answer... Its OK for me, that the other(full) answer was accepted. jbutler483 answer is good, so this question can be closed for more spam.